# Referring to instance variable with same name as a local variable in a constructor?

Tags: java, oop, syntax

This is a mostly theoretical example, but how do I refer to the instance variable "a" in the constructor, but not the current object variable "this.a", after a local variable "a" has been declared?

```
public class Foobar {
    public int a = 0;

    public Foobar(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Foobar(int b, int c) {
        a = b * c;
        int a = c;    //after this point, is there any way of refer to the instance variable a but not a in the current object (i.e. this.a)?

    }

    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foobar foo = new Foobar(3);
        Foobar bar = new Foobar(3, 1);

        System.out.println(foo.getA());

        System.out.println(bar.getA());
    }

}
```

Comment: The instance variable `a` and the current object variable `this.a` are the same variable.

Comment: There are only two variables, `this.a` and `a`. You have described how to refer to both.

Comment: But when you declare a local variable "a", it is no longer possible to refer to the class variable "a", only the instance variable (using "this.a"). Is that right?

Comment: No, it isn't right. It doesn't even make sense. There is no 'class variable `a`' here, unless you mean the 'instance variable `a`', which is therefore the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class variable in your code.

If you want a class variable, use `static int a`. Of course, you won't be able to refer to a class variable using `this.a`: that only works with instance variables.

And, of course, you can't have a class variable and an instance variable with the same name.

If you override the class variable with a local variable, (bad idea - don't do that - most IDEs will warn you) then can refer to the class variable with  `Foobar.a`